# Grafana - elasticsearch - using output of one query in another

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I want to use the output of one query in Grafana in another query for example:

[image]

As you can see in the picture there is possibility of two queries, query1 returns a unique identifier for each row (document), I then want to use that unique identifier of the row (document) and then use it in query two to get the whole document (other fields).

The result would be multiple rows (documents) one for each unique identifier.

How can this be accomplished with Grafana and Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Any luck with that? or what did you end up doing to merge 2 aggregates?

Comment: I don't have a solution implemented as of yet

Comment: try this plugin: https://github.com/GoshPosh/grafana-meta-queries